# Automatically set author and email in tt_news

Tags: typo3, tt-news

I know I can configure tt_news to automatically set author and email to a given value, like this:

```
TCAdefaults.tt_news.author = full name
TCAdefaults.tt_news.author_email = name@domain.tld
```

But could I retrieve the name an email from the info of the currently logged BE user instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To meake it possible to fill the values on every change (if empty), you need to register a hook somewhere ie, in your own extension

`typo3conf/ext/yourext/hooks/class.tx_ttnews_hooks.php`

```
class tx_ttnews_hooks {
// hook for prefilling TCA values
function getSingleField_preProcess($table, $field, &$row, $altName, $palette, $extra, $pal, $pObj) {

        switch($field) {
            case 'author_email':
                if($row[$field] == '') {
                    $row[$field] = $GLOBALS['BE_USER']->user['email'];
                }
                break;

            case 'author':
                if($row[$field] == '') {
                    $row[$field] = $GLOBALS['BE_USER']->user['realName'];
                }
                break;
         }
    }
}
```

and then add this into `typo3conf/ext/yourext/ext_localconf.php`:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tceforms.php']['getSingleFieldClass'][] 
    = 'EXT:yourext/hooks/class.tx_ttnews_hooks.php:tx_ttnews_hooks';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [extension](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/cron_setdefaultauthor) that does what you want. I haven't used it myself, but the description sounds pretty promising.

As another solution, you may write a little bit of php code that adds a dynamic user ts. I only found an [example in German](http://wissen.netzhaut.de/typo3/extensionentwicklung/tt_news-defaultwert-fur-archivierungsdatum/), but maybe that's helpful anyway.